# Line chart issue. Chart JS

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

Hi like in question I have a problem with drawing charts based on values in arrays.
Here is my code:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    let label = Array.from(Array(200).keys());
    const susbeptible = this.simulation.records.map(SeirdsRecord => SeirdsRecord.susceptible);
    const deaths = this.simulation.records.map(SeirdsRecord => SeirdsRecord.deaths);
    console.log(deaths);


    var seirdsChart = new Chart("seirdsChart", {
      type: 'line',
      labels: label,
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Susceptible",
            data: susbeptible,
            fill: false
          },
          {
            label: "Deaths",
            data: deaths,
            fill: false
          },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

susceptible and deaths are arrays that contains 200 values in range 0-40 000 000, but this code draw only the first two values per array like this:
[image]

Do somebody know what have I do to fix it? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `labels` is defined at the wrong place.

```
var seirdsChart = new Chart("seirdsChart", {
  type: 'line',
  labels: label,
  data: {
    datasets: [
      ...
```

It should be defined inside `data` as follows:

```
var seirdsChart = new Chart("seirdsChart", {
  type: 'line',      
  data: {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [
      ...
```